# AngularJS, DOM is not updated after updating model list

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs controller, inside it, there is a function shown below:

```
$scope.searchCustomersBy = function(circleuuid) {
    // get all the customers that belong to the circle
    console.log("searchCustomersBy "+circleuuid);
    console.log($scope.customersResults);
    var buddies = [];
    var results = [];
    var promise = $http.get('/api/customer/buddies?circleuuid='+circleuuid);
    promise = promise.then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        buddies = response.data;
        if (buddies.length > 0) {
            for (var i in $scope.customers) {
                if ( buddies.indexOf($scope.customers[i].uuid) >= 0)
                    results.push($scope.customers[i]);
            }
        }


        $scope.customersResults = results;

    }, function(err){
        console.error('failed to fetch the buddy list', err);
    });
};
```

And in the html page, the code that uses the list is like this:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerController">
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customersResults">
        ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    ...
</div>
```

All other parts using angularjs work just fine. The only problem is, after `searchCustomersBy` is called and `$scope.customersResults` is updated(I am pretty sure of that), the DOM is not updated at all.

It seems that the code doesn't work at all when I put it in the `promise`.

How should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Your example html won't display anything as written, since you don't appear to use customer. Is there more to it?

Comment: I know, I forget to mention that I already used the controller some where in the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are breaking the relationship between your model and the view when you

```
$scope.customersResults = results;
```

you are actually pointing  $scope.customersResults to a new memory address but the old data is not garbage collected because is tied to the DOM so you any changes to $scope.customersResults won't be observed anymore, the solution for this is to remove all content from the array w/o reassigning it you can do

```
$scope.customersResults.splice(0,$scope.customersResults.length)
$scope.customersResults=$scope.customersResults.concat(results);
```

that should work

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: in your fiddles angular version reassigning the array is actually not the issue.  the problem with the fiddle is that $http is missing from the controllers injected params and that your request is being made to a server that doesn't support CORS, any luck providing mocked list?

Comment: you solved the $http but the cors issue remains, you can't get the data from the server because it doesn't support cros domain requests, so the http call fails

Comment: I solved the problem, the reason is that customersResults should be a deep copy of customers, I can't simply use customersResults = customers to make assignment. Otherwise somehow the customers will be cleaned somewhere and I can't get info from customers nor customersResults anymore. But thanks very much for your time and help!!!